# How do you tell if a D&D book is 3.0 or 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, books

I'm new to d20. I recently acquired a bunch of D&D books and I'm sure they are all either 3.0 or 3.5, but it doesn't *say* in the book which version it is. How can I tell which version the book is?

For instance, I have "Complete Warrior - A Player's Guide to Combat for All Classes". It's hard back, published in '03. Is it 3.0 or 3.5?

Another example, I have "Sword and Fist - A Guidebook to Fighters and Monks". Perfect Bound, published in '01. Is it 3.0 or 3.5?

Comment: Related: [Do the D&D 5e source books specify which edition they are?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/do-the-dd-5e-source-books-specify-which-edition-they-are), [How do I know which edition of Dungeons and Dragons (D&D) the books I'm looking at are for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135571/how-do-i-know-which-edition-of-dungeons-and-dragons-dd-the-books-im-looking)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Note that [thefemmedm's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4407/77) indicates a spot in the book where you can look this up directly.

D&D3.5 was first published in July, 2003. Anything published by Wizards of the Coast after that date will almost certainly be for 3.5. Anything published before that date will certainly be for 3.0.

Except... Some books published close to the release of 3.5 (*Book of Vile Darkness*, *Savage Species*, a couple FR books) were published in a weird "3.25" state, using only some of the rules from the upcoming 3.5 (which had not yet been finalized).

Another source of information is vendors like Amazon.com. The edition will often be in the product description, as it is here:
[http://www.amazon.com/Complete-Warrior-Dungeons-Dragons-Roleplaying/dp/0786928808](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786928808)

Or, for your specific examples:

- Sword and Fist: 3.0 (too old to be 3.5).
- Complete Warrior: 3.5 (according to Amazon.com).

Based on my memory, Complete Warrior is essentially the 3.5 equivalent to Sword and Fist.

Answer (score 108):

For a quick answer turn to page 2 in the book, usually a brown-orange colour with all the designers' names, etc.

Look near the bottom of the page where it says "Based on the original Dungeons and Dragons rules [...], and Peter Atkinson."

Under this, if it is a 3.5 book, it will say:

> This product uses updated material from the v.3.5 revision.

If it's a 3.0 book, it will continue:

> This Wizards of the Coast game product [...]

Answer (score 49):

Use this handy list of...

## *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* and *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* Products from Wizards of the Coast in Order of Publication

The following presented in year/month order for easier sorting. Products released in the same month are presented alphabetically. Parenthetical references are official abbreviations gleaned Wizards of the Coast's [indices](https://web.archive.org/web/20211218141717/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/lists); some products lack abbreviations. Even abbreviations are italicized lest, for example, *Champions of Ruin* be confused with Challenge Rating, for instance. Wizards of the Coast makes available official [errata](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004060219/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20040125a). Starting with *The Speaker in Dreams*, Wizards of the Coast made available for many products online-only [Web enhancements](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111145513/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/we&page=2).

### *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition*

*Dragon* #275-308, *Dragon Annual* #5 and #6, and *Dungeon* #81-99 present *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* content. *Dragon* #298 and *Dungeon* #94 see Paizo publishing the magazines under license from Wizards of the Coast. Paizo published no *Dragon Annuals*.

- 2000/08 *Dungeons and Dragons Character Sheets*
- 2000/08 *Player's Handbook*<sup>1</sup> (*PH*)
- 2000/08 *Sunless Citadel* (*SC*)
- 2000/09 *Dungeon Master's Guide*<sup>1</sup> (*DMG*)
- 2000/09 *Dungeons and Dragons Gazeteer* (*DG*)
- 2000/09 *Dungeon Master's Screen*
- 2000/10 *Into the Dragon's Lair*
- 2000/10 *Monster Manual*<sup>1</sup> (*MM*)
- 2000/11 *Forge of Fury* (*Fo*)
- 2000/11 *Living Greyhawk Gazeteer*
- 2000/11 *Pool of Radiance: Attack on Myth Drannor*
- 2000/12 *Hero Builder's Guidebook* (*HBG*)
- 2001/01 *Speaker in Dreams* (*SD*)
- 2001/01 *Sword and Fist*<sup>2</sup> (*SF*)
- 2001/02 *Monsters of Faerûn*<sup>3</sup> (*Mon*)
- 2001/03 *Psionics Handbook*
- 2001/04 *Standing Stone* (*StS*)
- 2001/05 *Defenders of the Faith*<sup>2</sup> (*DF*)
- 2001/06 *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*<sup>4</sup> (*FRCS*)
- 2001/06 *Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil* (*RT*)
- 2001/07 *Heart of Nightfang Spire* (*HN*)
- 2001/07 *Tome and Blood*<sup>2</sup> (*TB*)
- 2001/08 *Magic of Faerûn*<sup>4</sup> (*Mag*)
- 2001/09 *Manual of the Planes*<sup>1</sup> (*MP*)
- 2001/10 *Enemies and Allies* (*EA*)
- 2001/10 *Oriental Adventures*<sup>5</sup> (*OA*)
- 2001/11 *Deep Horizon* (*DH*)
- 2001/11 *Lords of Darkness*<sup>4</sup> (*LD*)
- 2001/12 *Song and Silence*<sup>2</sup> (*SaS*)
- 2002/01 *Lord of the Iron Fortress* (*LF*)
- 2002/02 *Forgotten Realms Dungeon Master's Screen*
- 2002/02 *Masters of the Wild*<sup>2</sup> (*MW*)
- 2002/03 *Bastion of Broken Souls* (*BB*)
- 2002/04 *Deities and Demigods*<sup>1</sup> (*DD*)
- 2002/05 *Faiths and Pantheons*<sup>4</sup> (*FP*)
- 2002/05 *Stronghold Builder's Guidebook* (*SB*)
- 2002/06 *Book of Challenges* (*BC*)
- 2002/07 *Epic Level Handbook*<sup>1</sup> (*EL*)
- 2002/08 *Silver Marches*<sup>4</sup> (*SM*)
- 2002/09 *City of the Spider Queen*<sup>4</sup> (*CSQ*)
- 2002/09 *Monster Manual II*<sup>1</sup> (*MM2*)
- 2002/10 *Book of Vile Darkness* (*BV*)
- 2003/02 *Savage Species* (*SS*)
- 2003/03 *Arms and Equipment Guide* (*AE*)
- 2003/03 *Races of Faerûn*<sup>4</sup> (*Rac*)
- 2003/04 *Fiend Folio*<sup>1</sup> (*FF*)
- 2003/05 *Unapproachable East*<sup>4</sup> (*Una*)
- 2003/06 *Ghostwalk*<sup>6</sup> (*Gh*)

#### Notes

<sup>**1**</sup> *Player's Handbook*, *Dungeon Master's Guide*, *Monster Manual*, *Manual of the Planes*, *Deities and Demigods*, *Epic Level Handbook*, *Monster Manual II*, and *Fiend Folio* are updated to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* *via* the [*Dungeons and Dragons 3.5 Accessory Update Booklet*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111163406/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a).
<sup>**2**</sup> The article ["Rules Reference: Feats, Prestige Classes, and Spells"](https://web.archive.org/web/20211118120255/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20050110x) lists titular items from the *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* class guidebooks that were updated to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*. Its most recent revision is Jan. 2005.
<sup>**3**</sup> *Monsters of Faerûn* is updated to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* *via* the *Player's Guide to Faerûn* Web enhancement ["*Player's Guide to Faerûn*: Monster Update."](https://web.archive.org/web/20191104064348/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20040313a)
<sup>**4**</sup> *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* and *Magic of Faerûn* receive major updates and *Lords of Darkness*, *Faiths and Pantheons*, *Silver Marches*, *City of the Spider Queen*, *Races of Faerûn*, and *Unapproachable East* receive minor updates to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* *via* the *Player's Guide to Faerûn* (5).
<sup>**5**</sup> *Oriental Adventures* is updated to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* *via* the *Dragon* #318 article "Oriental Adventures Update: Eastern Flavor" (32-48).
<sup>**6**</sup> *Ghostwalk* is updated to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* *via* the *Ghostwalk* Web enhancement ["*Ghostwalk*, Part 2: *Ghostwalk* 3.5 Update."](https://web.archive.org/web/20200105202451/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20031225a)

### *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*

Wizards of the Coast explains the purpose of *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* in the Revision Spotlight column ["Compiled *D&D* Revision Spotlight."](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031220422/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rsa/archive)

*Dragon* #309 and *Dungeon* #100 present *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* content. *Dragon* #359 and *Dungeon* #150 are the last *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* issues and the last published by Paizo after Wizards of the Coast doesn't renew Paizo's magazine licenses (see Wizards of the Coast's [announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031214356/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/news/20070419a) and Paizo's [announcement](https://paizo.com/transition)). Although officially licensed by Wizards of the Coast, *Dragon Compendium Volume 1* (Oct. 2005) is published by Paizo; Paizo makes available for it [errata](https://paizo.com/download/dragon/compendium/DragonCompendiumVolumeIErrata.pdf).

- 2003/06 *Dungeon Master's Guide* (*DMG*)
- 2003/07 *Monster Manual* (*MM*)
- 2003/07 *Player's Handbook* (*PH*)
- 2003/08 *Dragonlance Campaign Setting*<sup>1</sup> (*DCS*)
- 2003/08 *Dungeon Master's Screen*
- 2003/09 *Miniatures Handbook* (*MH*)
- 2003/10 *Book of Exalted Deeds* (*BE*)
- 2003/10 *Underdark* (*Und*)
- 2003/11 *Draconomicon* (*Dr*)
- 2003/12 *Complete Warrior* (*CW*)
- 2004/01 *Deluxe Character Sheets*
- 2004/01 *Deluxe Dungeon Master's Screen*
- 2004/02 *Unearthed Arcana* (*UA*)
- 2004/03 *Player's Guide to Faerûn* (*PG*)
- 2004/04 *Expanded Psionics Handbook* (*XPH*)
- 2004/04 *Map Folio I*
- 2004/05 *Complete Divine* (*CD*)
- 2004/06 *Eberron Campaign Setting* (*ECS*)
- 2004/07 *Planar Handbook* (*PlH*)
- 2004/07 *Serpent Kingdoms* (*SK*)
- 2004/07 *Shadows of the Last War* (*SL*)
- 2004/08 *Map Folio II*
- 2004/08 *Races of Stone* (*RS*)
- 2004/09 *Frostburn* (*Fr*)
- 2004/09 *Monster Manual III* (*MM3*)
- 2004/10 *Libris Mortis* (*LM*)
- 2004/10 *Dungeon Master's Guide* (special edition) (*DMG*)
- 2004/10 *Player's Handbook* (special edition) (*PH*)
- 2004/10 *Monster Manual* (special edition) (*MM*)
- 2004/10 *Shining South* (*ShS*)
- 2004/10 *Whispers of the Vampire's Blade* (*WB*)
- 2004/11 *Complete Arcane* (*CAr*)
- 2004/11 *Sharn: City of Towers* (*Sh*)
- 2004/12 *Races of Destiny* (*RD*)
- 2004/12 *Map Folio 3-D*
- 2005/01 *Complete Adventurer* (*CAd*)
- 2005/01 *Grasp of the Emerald Claw* (*GC*)
- 2005/02 *Lost Empires of Faerûn* (*LE*)
- 2005/02 *Races of the Wild* (*RW*)
- 2005/03 *Sandstorm* (*Sa*)
- 2005/04 *Lords of Madness* (*LoM*)
- 2005/04 *Races of Eberron* (*RE*)
- 2005/05 *Champions of Ruin* (*CR*)
- 2005/05 *Heroes of Battle* (*HB*)
- 2005/06 *City of Splendors: Waterdeep* (*CSW*)
- 2005/06 *Dungeon Master's Guide II* (*DMG2*)
- 2005/07 *Eberron Deluxe Dungeon Master's Screen*
- 2005/07 *Five Nations* (*FN*)
- 2005/07 *Weapons of Legacy* (*WL*)
- 2005/08 *Eberron Player Character Sheets*
- 2005/08 *Explorer's Handbook* (*EH*)
- 2005/08 *Stormwrack* (*Sto*)
- 2005/09 *Fantastic Locations: Fane of the Drow* (*FLFD*)
- 2005/09 *Magic of Incarnum* (*MoI*)
- 2005/09 *Sons of Gruumsh* (*SG*)
- 2005/10 *Heroes of Horror* (*HH*)
- 2005/10 *Magic of Eberron* (*MoE*)
- 2005/11 *Champions of Valor* (*CV*)
- 2005/11 *Fantastic Locations: Hellspike Prison* (*FLHP*)
- 2005/12 *Spell Compendium* (*SpC*)
- 2006/01 *Player's Guide to Eberron* (*PE*)
- 2006/01 *Races of the Dragon* (*RDr*)
- 2006/02 *Red Hand of Doom* (*RH*)
- 2006/03 *Power of Faerûn* (*PF*)
- 2006/03 *Tome of Magic* (*TM*)
- 2006/04 *Complete Psionic* (*CP*)
- 2006/04 *Fantastic Locations: Fields of Ruin* (*FLFR*)
- 2006/04 *Voyage of the* Golden Dragon (*VGD*)
- 2006/05 *Player's Handbook II* (*PH2*)
- 2006/06 *Fiendish Codex I* (*FC1*)
- 2006/06 *Mysteries of the Moonsea* (*Mys*)
- 2006/07 *Fantastic Locations: Dragondown Grotto*
- 2006/07 *Monster Manual IV* (*MM4*)
- 2006/07 *Secrets of Xen'drik* (*SX*)
- 2006/08 *Dragons of Faerûn* (*DrF*)
- 2006/08 *Tome of Battle* (*ToB*)
- 2006/09 *Dragon Magic* (*DM*)
- 2006/09 *Faiths of Eberron* (*FE*)
- 2006/09 *Twilight Tomb*
- 2006/10 *Complete Mage* (*CM*)
- 2006/10 *Expedition to Castle Ravenloft* (*Rav*)
- 2006/11 *Cityscape* (*Ci*)
- 2006/11 *Dragonmarked* (*Dra*)
- 2006/11 *Scourge of the Howling Horde*
- 2006/12 *Animated Series Handbook*<sup>2</sup>
- 2006/12 *Fantastic Locations: The Frostfell Rift*
- 2006/12 *Fiendish Codex II* (*FC2*)
- 2006/12 *Shattered Gates of Slaughtergarde* (*ShG*)
- 2007/01 *Complete Scoundrel* (*CS*)
- 2007/02 *Barrow of the Forgotten King* (*BFK*)
- 2007/02 *Dungeonscape* (*Du*)
- 2007/02 *Secrets of Sarlona* (*SoS*)
- 2007/03 *Magic Item Compendium* (*MIC*)
- 2007/03 *Cormyr: The Tearing of the Weave* (*Co*)
- 2007/04 *Eyes of the Lich Queen* (*ELQ*)
- 2007/04 *Expedition to the Demonweb Pits* (*EDP*)
- 2007/04 *Fantastic Locations: City in Peril* (*CiP*)
- 2007/05 *Complete Champion* (*CC*)
- 2007/05 *Drow of the Underdark* (*DrU*)
- 2007/06 *Expedition to Undermountain* (*EU*)
- 2007/06 *Forge of War* (*FW*)
- 2007/06 *Sinister Spire* (*SiS*)
- 2007/07 *Monster Manual V* (*MM5*)
- 2007/07 *Shadowdale: The Scouring of the Land* (*SSL*)
- 2007/08 *Expedition to the Ruins of Greyhawk* (*ERG*)
- 2007/09 *Exemplars of Evil* (*EE*)
- 2007/09 *Fortress of the Yuan-Ti* (*FY*)
- 2007/09 *Grand History of the Realms* (*GHR*)
- 2007/10 *Dragons of Eberron* (*DE*)
- 2007/10 *Rules Compendium* (*RC*)
- 2007/11 *Anauroch: The Empire of Shade* (*An*)
- 2007/12 *Elder Evils* (*ElE*)
- 2008/02 *City of Stormreach*
- 2008/03 *An Adventurer's Guide to Eberron*
- 2012/08 *Dungeon Master's Guide* (premium edition) (*DMG*)
- 2012/08 *Monster Manual* (premium edition) (*MM*)
- 2012/08 *Player's Handbook* (premium edition) (*PH*)
- 2013/04 *Spell Compendium* (premium edition) (*SpC*)
- 2013/07 *Magic Item Compendium* (premium edition) (*MIC*)

#### Notes

<sup>**1**</sup> *Dragonlance Campaign Setting* is published by Wizards of the Coast; subsequent products in the line are officially licensed by Wizards of the Coast but not published by Wizards of the Coast.
<sup>**2**</sup> *Animated Series Handbook*'s 2007 printed publication year contradicts the release date of BCI's [*Dungeons and Dragons: The Complete Animated Series*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000JBXY44) which included the *Animated Series Handbook*. Mill Creek Entertainment's August 2009 [*Dungeons and Dragons: The Complete Animated Series*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002DH20Q0) doesn't include the *Animated Series Handbook*.

---

*ENWorld*'s Wiki article ["*Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* Collector's Guide"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610014223/http://www.enworld.org:80/forum/showwiki.php?title=3rd-Edition-D-and-D-Collectors-Guide) was essential for making this list.

---

Officially licensed products—products bearing some combination of the *Dungeons and Dragons* logo and the Wizards of the Coast officially licensed product seal or including on their title pages that the product is officially licensed by Wizards of the Coast—include the following:

- AEG's Oriental Adventures product line that's also for the *Legend of the Five Rings, Second Edition* role-playing game (except *Bloodspeakers*).
- Arthaus's Raveloft product line.
- Arthaus's [*Warcraft: The Roleplaying Game*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1588460711) but not other products in that line.
- Kenzer and Company's Kingdoms of Kalamar product line until about 2003.
- Sovereign Press's Dragonlance product line until early 2008.

Some Web sites were given official permission to create new material for defunct settings. Sites support the settings [Birthright](http://birthright.net/), [Dark Sun](https://web.archive.org/web/20221011160512/http://www.athas.org/), [Mystara](http://pandius.com/), [Planescape](https://planewalker.com/), and [Spelljammer](http://www.spelljammer.org/).

---

#### Relevant Questions

- [Are Kenzer and Company's officially licensed Kalamar products, which bear the *Dungeons and Dragons* logo, *really* official?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28844/is-kalamar-campaign-setting-official-or-3rd-party)
- [What are the differences between *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* and *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/how-compatible-are-books-for-dd-3-0-and-dd-3-5)

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119659/discussion-on-answer-by-hey-i-can-chan-how-do-you-tell-if-a-dd-book-is-3-0-or-3).

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for the curation assistance. Most welcome.

Comment: I think that this list is omitting the 3.0 adventure The Sunless Citadel. I'm not sure where exactly on the list it should go, but it's definitely before The Forge of Fury, since that was the second adventure in that series.

Comment: @nick012000 *SC* was there, but the date was wrong. Fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to all the other answers, which are quite accurate, you can also tell from looking at classes or characters.  If they have skills like Intuit Direction, Innuendo, Animal Handling, Wilderness Lore, or a single Perform skill, it's a 3.0 book.  If it instead has Slight of Hand, Survival, and Perform (type) skills, it's a 3.5 book.

For third party material, which often doesn't specify clearly which version of the SRD it's based on, this can be a more useful way.

Comment: My usual tactic is to look for something that has damage reduction. In 3.0, it's specified as two numbers: X/+Y, where Y is the enhancement bonus needed to overcome the DR. In 3.5, DR is a number and a word: X/condition, where condition describes something about the attack that determined whether or not it overcomes damage reduction.

Comment: Do note that 3.5 classes have Handle Animal, which might be a source of confusion...

Answer (score 9):

There are several databases out there which will tell you such things (besides Googling in general or checking Amazon).

RPG.net has [a searchable index](http://index.rpg.net/) of most any RPG product ever.  Search it for "Complete Warrior" and it says "Wizards of the Coast: Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 (2003 Hardcover)" in the search results even.

RPG Geek (a variant site off BoardGameGeek) also has a [huge searchable index](http://rpggeek.com/).    Searching that for "Complete Warrior" gets a search result that says "Dungeons & Dragons (3.5 Edition) - d20 System" concisely in its search results.

Between these two, no RPG product question ever needs to go unanswered.

Answer (score 8):

There is a handy [online database of roleplaying games](http://rpggeek.com/) called [RPG Geek](http://rpggeek.com/) that you can search.

If you put "Sword and Fist" into the search box, it gives you [this result](http://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=rpgunified&q=Sword+and+Fist&B1=Go). Notice that it lists the game and the edition in a hierarchy above the title of the book in the search result (as well as on the book's page if you click through). Sword and Fist happens to be for "3rd Edition". Similarly, [the search result for *Complete Warrior*](http://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=rpgunified&q=Complete+Warrior&B1=Go)  lists it under "3.5 Edition".

This will work for any D&D book you have. If there were two versions of a book, one for 3 and one for 3.5, then you should be able to tell which one you have by comparing it to the book covers in the database.

Answer (score 2):

It's 3.0. 3.5 has been released in 2003, so it's likely that anything you have is 3.0. In any case, the differences between 3.0 and 3.5 are minimal. Yes, there are some, but porting anything 3.0 to 3.5 is generally a minor issue.