# What are all the playable races and starting classes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, class, prestige-class, races

I'm about to start a *Dungeons and Dragon 3.5* adventure, and the last time I created a character I didn't feel there were many options to choose from (unlike *Dungeons and Dragons, 4th Edition*). What playable races and starting classes are available in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*?

Comment: This question is actually quite large. What resources does the game allow?

Comment: Have you looked at the srd?

Comment: I was just wanting to know if there are more races than dwarf, elf, half-elf, half-orc, halfing, gnome, and Human.

Comment: It will depend on what resources the game allows outside the core books.

Comment: Roll back the edit if it's not to your satisfaction.

Comment: This is way too broad, and the only answer to what's written right now is a huge list (or a link to a huge list).

Comment: The huge list is hard to find.  A question on here with a link to the huge list is better than nothing.

Comment: I feel like this is an XY Problem. Instead of asking "Are there any more races than the PHB offers?" it asked instead for what they would assume solves their problem: a full list. Edit this to "Are there races other than what's in the PHB" and it's answerable. Trivial, but answerable.

Comment: True. He could do that and ask "What classes are there outside of the PHB?". Is the list still on wizards.com? Edit: It appears it is, just moved. http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/class Terrible list with lots of duplicates, but it has a full list.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots, too many to list here, and it will depend on which books the game has available for use and if things like LA are allowed. There is a (mostly complete, last updated Oct 2007) [list of races](https://web.archive.org/web/20180922083446/http://chet.kindredcircle.org/pdf/DnD3.5Index-Races.pdf) (PDF) along with book references, collected by Chet Erez.

There is also a similar (to Feb 2007) [index of base classes](https://files.meetup.com/9451892/DnD3.5Index-Classes-Base.pdf) (PDF) that also includes variants, also collected by Chet Erez.

Comment: Chet's indices are very useful, but they are missing some notable material from later books.

Comment: Are they? That's unfortunate (at least he lists some of the missing information). Still I'm not sure if there's a more complete list out there. Possibly the ones on the wizards or brilliant gamologists forums, though I haven't looked at them.

Comment: I dig on Chet's stuff, too, but KRyan's correct that it tapers off about midway through [2007](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610). I can't upvote this answer until the question's updated because even Chet omits things many would include (e.g. psionic classes).

Answer (score 5):

## Classes

[Character Class List on archive.wizards.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112033039/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/class)

[Prestige Class List on archive.wizards.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211105072854/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/prc)

Every source for every class. Many classes are listed repeatedly since they can be found in multiple books (*Eberron Campaign Setting* and *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* each discuss all the core classes and how they exist in those settings, for example), but the list should be absolutely complete. As you can see, there are a *lot*, and there are several times as many prestige classes as base classes.

## Races

There are no official lists of playable races; Wizards only has a more general monster index. Chet’s index is very useful, but not totally complete.

[The Master 3.5 Playable Race List](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1281.0) should be pretty close to complete, though, being a community effort updated steadily over time. It only lists LA +0 races (i.e. no monstrous or "powerful" races), but links to a pretty good list of LA +1 and +2 races. Races with an actual LA (i.e. not LA –) are playable under the rules, but in practice become increasingly unplayable as more LA is added; even +1 or +2 is extremely problematic.