# What special materials exist for weapons and armor in D&D 3.5 and Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, special-materials

Can anyone give me a good reference to a relatively complete list of Item Special Materials, such as Adamantine, Mithril, etc? Most sources are so spread out and lack vital information that it's difficult to find anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 14):

## *D&D 3.5* [special materials](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?442820-Special-Materials-Index)

The most complete list of official special materials published for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* that I could find is the user terronus's salvaged-from-the-Wizards-of-the-Coast-forums Special Materials Index [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?442820-Special-Materials-Index), hosted on the *Giant in the Playground* forums.

Although terronus's Special Materials Index really should be sufficient for most campaigns, keep in mind that even it omits, for example, special materials from the Bazaar of the Bizarre column "Secrets of the Master Smiths" (*Dragon Annual* #5 38-40), the special material [ferroplasm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53681/are-there-any-other-psionically-active-metaloids) (*Psionics Handbook* 138), and the special material nepthelium (*Sunless Citadel* 32), this last so obscure I was unaware of it until finding this [thread](http://mimir.planewalker.com/forum/need-list-special-materialssubstances-2e-books) (also a valuable resource yet less navigable). (So you needn't look it up, metal weapons and armor made from nepthelium cost 100 gp more and appear transparent or gemlike; this has no mechanical effects.)

## *Pathfinder* [special materials](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials)

The *d20PFSRD* compiles *Pathfinder*'s ever-growing list of 1st- and 3rd-party special materials [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials).

Comment: How does the linked list compare to Chet Eretz’s, the ones formerly hosted on Crystal Keep? I know Chet’s are missing quite a few late things but they were remarkably good about hitting obscure sources during the timeframe they cover.

Comment: @KRyan  Chet Eraz's [list](http://www.mithrilcircle.com/Chells/RPG/DD_Guides/DnD3.5Index-Equipment.pdf) (Warning:  PDF) is strangely incomplete. I think it excludes all the still-relevant *Third Edition* sources, psionics, much of Eberron, and a lot of the later books and even later magazines.

Comment: (By 2018 the Special Material Index that's hosted on the *Giant in the Playground* forums had been updated to include most of the materials mentioned in this answer. Thank you, Bullet06320, for keeping the index in shape! It's a valuable resource for the community.)

Comment: Shouldn't we probably copy the lists to here so that the answer does not depend on the links?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Possibly? The issue is that the lists are lengthy, extensive, and—for the past several years—stable elsewhere. So while ideally both games' tables would be *better* here, they're more *functional* as links. I mean, I think I push the site's limits with some of my longer answers, but I think an answer that saw a transliteration of those tables would turn out far longer than even [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610) and be even *less* generally useful.

Answer (score 7):

Try have a look at this, it is a link to the Pathfinder materials listed.

[Special Materials](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials)

As for the D&D 3.5e, that is as you say spread out. The most complete/full lists I find are:

[dnd-wiki](http://www.dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Canon:Special_Materials) / [dungeons wikia](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/DnDWiki:Special_Materials) / [mundane materials (dnd-wiki)](http://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/3.5e_Mundane_Materials)

Comment: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm is a good link too.

Comment: Yes, I found that too, but I didn't incl it as it only showed a few. I found it not to be a complete/full list.

Comment: Does anyone know if there would be any reprecussions or any anger at trying to put together an unofficial list of materials from 3.x and Pathfinder and from all the splats I can find? 

Also, I've had those sources for a while now, and also found a splat called Planar Metals that has some good things in it... 

Can anyone give links to materials or lists that are not listed in these articles?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of homebrew.

Comment: @AOKost if the thing was published in any way where it's useful to a large amount of people (i.e. on the Internet) it would probably get a cease and desist letter from the game owners, since it is considered piracy (except for the material under the Open Gaming License that is already consolidated on www.d20srd.com)