# Are there any other Psionically-active metaloids?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, psionics

Are there any other Psionically-active metaloids besides Riedran crysteel? From what I remember and have been able to find, besides crystals, Riendran Crysteel is the only metal that allows the use of psionic abilities.

If there are any others, what are they?

This material will be used in weapons primarily. I'm trying to find a metaloid that psionic classes can use instead of requireing cryastal... I'm trying to qualify for 2 different classes, one that uses metal weapons, and the other that specifically requires a crystal weapon. My DM said that if I could find a metal that allowed psionic abilities to be used that I could use that weapon for both classes as a go-between. So far the closest that I've been ablet o find is Riedran Crysteel... I'm wondering if there's any other materials available. Any 3.X source is available in our game setting as long as I can show where it's from (regardless if we actually have the material or not).

The two classes are Psychic Weapon Master and Disciple of Dispater. I'm taking 2 levels of Fighter, 5 levels of Psion to qualify for Psychic weapon Master, and then Disciple of Dispater. To gain the full benifits of both classes (I don't plan on taking all 10 levels of both), my dm has told me that I must find a metal that can be used by psions, as metals are inherantly crystaline. That will allow me to use the benifits from BOTH classes. So far, the only metal that I've found that comes close is Riedran Crysteel.

Are there any other, better metals out there that I can use?

Comment: Thank you for helping the question be a bit more understandable, I'm rather poor at asking questions on this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a weapon made of **ferroplasm** will do?

> Mined from secret locations in the Astral Plane, this malleable metal holds its shape only in the hands of a psionic being. When an item forged with ferroplasm is unattended or held by a nonpsionic creature, it melts and temporarily loses all special powers. But when wielded by, psionic creature, such an item immediately springs bad into its true shape and regains all abilities. In its proper form, a ferroplasm item glows with a violet light (illuminating a 10-foot-radius), unless the item’s owner mentally quenches it. In an area where psionic powers do not function, it collapses as if in the hands of a nonpsionic creature. ...
>
> Weapons fashioned from ferroplasm have a natural enhancement bonus to attack and damage.... These bonuses do not stack with other enhancement bonuses. Weapons or armor fashioned from ferroplasm are treated as masterwork items with regard to creation times, but the masterwork quality does not affect the enhancement bonus of weapons....
>
> Ferroplasm has hardness 20 and 40 hit points per inch of thickness when in its true form, and a hardness of 5 and 10 hit points per inch of thickness when soft. (*Psionics Handbook* 138)<sup>1</sup>

A weapon made of ferroplasm that deals 1d4 or 1d6 points of damage gains a +1 enhancement bonus and costs an additional 2,500 gp, while a weapon made of ferroplasm that deals 1d8, 1d10, or 1d12 points of damage gains a +2 enhancement bonus and costs an additional 7,500 gp.

Alternatively, how about a **sentira** weapon?

> This bizarre material is wrought by Chosen, Inspired, and (rarely) kalashtar who use powdered crystal and the power of their thoughts and emotions, also draw­ing on the essence of Dal Quor. Sentira items are liter­ally grown into their final form. They have an organic,
>   whorled appearance, much like horn or shell, with a shimmering, opalescent surface. Color varies based on the emotion used to create the particular batch.
>
> Sentira is lightweight and almost unbreakable. Because of its resonant properties, it is an ideal material for emo­tional armor. For purposes other than those described in this chapter, sentira is treated as mithral.
>
> Sentira can be formed, sculpted, and repaired only by psionic creatures that have the Craft (sentira) skill. Such craftspersons, known in Riedra as thoughtweavers, must expend 1 power point for each day of work on a sentira object, whether building or repairing it. (*Secrets of Sarlona* 135)

Sentira is, you'll note, made of "powdered crystal" but "treated as mithril"--I don't know if that's close enough for the DM (or a chem professor), but at least the description *mentions* another metal, albeit a fictional one. Interestingly, although no statistics are given for making weapons from the sentira, everything *else* in *Secrets of Sarlona* is made of sentira (e.g. armor, mosaics, gates, public art installations, passports, *entire buildings*). It'll be up to the DM to determine the price of sentira weapon. I suggest he be guided by the special abilities and costs of emotional armor (137-8).

---

1. Yes, the *Psionics Handbook*, **not** the *Expanded Psionics Handbook*. The special material ferroplasm doesn't appear to have been republished for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* making the *Psionics Handbook* version oddly *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* compliant.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but in the description, it doesn't say that it's any form of metaloid... It sounds like an awesome substance, but it's not a metaloid...

Comment: @AOKost ...And that made me actually look up [metalloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid): "There is no standard definition of a metalloid, nor is there complete agreement as to which elements are appropriately classified as such." Learned something new this year already. Good luck in your quest.

Comment: You are right, but the general consensus that I've heard in Chemistry is that metaloids are any eliment or alloy of emements where the primary element is a metal, such as Iron, Tungsten, Aluminum, Tin, Bronze and Steel being examples of alloys. So for what I'm looking for is a metal that can be used by Psionic classes. Crystal is the general go-to, but since there is Rierdan Crysteel, I was hoping there might be another metal similar, or more active...

Comment: @AOKost What *are* the classes for which you need a weapon made of this stuff? (That should probably be part of the question, by the way.)

Comment: Psychic Weapon Master and Disciple of Dispater (re-fluffed for our campaign, but it's basically exactly the same class and requirements)

Comment: I do believe we have a winner! :D Sentira sounds ideal, as it mentions that it acts in all ways like Mithril. My DM doesn't care if it's a fake metal, so long as it's an accpetable metal for game purposes. He okayed Crysteel, but this sounds like it will work better for the game! :D Thank you again!

Comment: Sentira sounds like it will work rather well. Thank you for posting that material. The fact that it's a crystal that acts like Mithril, will probably work, as my DM has already aproved Deep Crystal as of tonight... Thanks again for all the hard work! :D

Answer (score 1):

I have to imagine you’re aware of them since they are part of the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/items/specialMaterials.htm), but both crystal (which isn’t particularly psionic) and deep crystal (which decidedly is; 2 power points can be channeled into it to add +2d6 damage to an attack) function identically to steel for all material and mechanical purposes, and counts as metal for druids’ purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it's not a metaloid...

Comment: @AOKost "A metalloid is a chemical element with properties in between, or that are a mixture of, those of metals and nonmetals. There is no standard definition of a metalloid, nor is there complete agreement as to which elements are appropriately classified as such." They're named crystals, but have all the physical and mechanical properties of steel, and count as metal for druids. In what sense do they fail to be metalloids? The word basically just means "metal-like" which is *exactly* what they are.

Comment: @AOKost Per your other comment about disciple of Dispater: if it counts as metal for druids, it should as well count for the disciple. Granted, there are *really good **mechanical** reasons* for your DM to disallow that particular combination, at least if Lightning Maces, Roundhouse Kick, and/or *aptitude* are available, but the fluff isn't really a good reason here.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. These are considerations that my DM and I have already discussed. The plan was to  take 2 Flaws (Murkey eyes, and Shakey) to get 2 extra feats, play as a human Fighter (2 levels) and go with Exotic Weapon Proficiency: Chainblade, Weapon Focus (Chainblade), Power attack, Disciple of Darkness, Dodge, Mobility, then Psion (5 levels) and take Psionic Dodge, Psionic Weapon Focus. Then Take 7 levels of Disciple of Dispater, and 8 levels of Psychic Weapon Master, taking Improved Critical, Cleave, Great Cleave and Knockdown along the way along with other feats...

Comment: I'll discuss the implications of Deep Crystal not being usible by Druids because it's considered metal with my DM... Maybe we can agree to refluff Deep Crystal just enough to make it usable as well... Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Although some of [this article](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/pse/20030426a) is likely to have been obsoleted by the *XPH* released a year later, the sidebar Crystal Weapons and Armor speaks to this issue almost directly.