# 3.5e rules on racial feats at character creation

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, feats, races, feat-qualifications

> Racial Feats. Depending on the creature type of the character’s race,
>   he begins with a number of feats. These feats may be used however the
>   character likes, provided he meets the prerequisites before adding any
>   class levels. **Feats requiring other feats as prerequisites are
>   permissible, as long as the required feats are selected at the same
>   time.** Because the character gains these racial feats, **he does not gain
>   a feat when he adds his first level of a character class**.
>   (Races of Faerûn, pg 7)

So this passage says two things to me:

1. If you get racial feats, you don't get a class feat at first level
2. If one of your racial feats requires other feats, you can take them
       at character creation before adding your class.

The question is, how are you able to take more feats [if a racial feat requires them], especially if you also are not getting the first level class feat?

Comment: *Races of Faerûn* was published for [*Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610). I'm not sure if this alters the core of your question, but knowing that might help the edges.

Comment: What I'm saying is, racial Hit Dice and Effective Character Level and Level Adjustment and feats gained due to creature type because of their natural Hit Dice and all that stuff was changed substantially in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*. That is, do you want a *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* answer to your question *or* do you want a history of racial Hit Dice between editions *or* do you want to know if these rules still apply *or* something else?

Comment: **Feats requiring other feats as prerequisites are permissible, as long as the required feats are selected at the same time.** How does this work?/what does this part mean?

Comment: If you update the question to reflect the comments, the question stands a better chance of being reopened, and then more folks can try to answer it.

Comment: O, hey, I'm sorry. Welcome to the site! Please, take the [tour]! Your question's been closed because some folks (including me) thought that it was unclear. That's not, like, *punishment* or anything (in fact, [it happens all the time](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5758/8610)) but a safety net to make sure you get the answers you want. You can edit your question whenever you want. Thank you for participating, and I apologize for not welcoming you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting (3.0) has a list of Regional feats and the Players Guide to Faerûn (3.5) updated that list. Unless I am mistaken a single Regional Feat along with a single Racial Feat are available but only at 1st level.

In addition, certain classes have automatic Feats at 1st Level. A fighter and a Human get insane feat bonuses. The DM II also had the Woodsman Mentor (p. 178) which gave a limited Track Feat, but of course you would then need to take the Apprentice Feat first, unless you use this for a zero-level character HouseRule or something.

There are a number of ways you get to take more than one feat at first level.