# DnD 3.5(e) source books

Tags: dnd-3.5e, books

I'm currently playing a DnD 3.5 campaign and the only sources we are currently using are: the PHB, the Dungeon Master Handbook, the Monster manual.

Now there seem to be a lot of other books out there, some belonging to DnD 3.5, some not. I'm a bit confused as towards how it all works. I understand of course that we can just choose what books to use. But **which books are considered part of DnD 3.5**? And is there a difference to DnD 3.5e? (i.e. what does the e stand for?)

Comment: [This question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1138/15469) is *almost* certainly a duplicate, but this one is somewhat confusing to me, so I'll let others judge.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, "DnD 3.5e" just means "3.5 Edition" and means *exactly* the same thing as "DnD 3.5". The first, more substantial, part of your question is answered by the question that Miniman has linked to.