# What are the final polymorph rules?

Tags: spells, dnd-3e, polymorph

The *polymorph self* spell and its friends were an ever-changing pile of errata. What was the final word on how polymorph effects work in *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*? I am uninterested in the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* rules for polymorph effects.

Comment: Hey I Can Chan's cleanup of this question is good and captures my intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [*Tome and Blood*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786918454) is the final word on those spells… *probably*

Andy Collins, he of the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* revision, says in the Wizards of the Coast Design and Development Web column "[The Polymorph Problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031220126/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dd/20060216a)" that *Tome and Blood* is the most recent source for the spells.  I flipped through some *Third Edition* books post-*Tome and Blood* to confirm this and didn't find any later reprints of the *polymorph* spells. So, while it's possible errata later than *Tome and Blood* (July 2001) appeared on the Wizards of the Coast Web site or in *Dungeon* or *Dragon*, I've not been able to locate any.

A few months prior to *Tome and Blood*, the spell *polymorph other* did appear as Official Errata from the Sage on page 45 of *Dragon* #280 (Feb. 2001). Also, I've *Psionics Handbook* errata from May 2002 that includes the text of the 4th-level psion/psychic warrior power *polymorph self* [psychometabolism] (*Psionics Handbook* 92) that's different from the *Tome and Blood* spell *polymorph other* and *self*, even after accounting for a necessary switch in pronouns and targets, but this undated [PDF](http://jtevans.kilnar.com/rpg/dnd/laenwold/addendum/PsionicsHBErrata.pdf) claiming to be *Psionics Handbook* errata includes the *Tome and Blood* version of *polymorph self* (altered appropriately from *other* and to a psionic power), so I don't know what's up with those.

By the way, [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20050905030359/http://www-hep.colorado.edu:80/%7Ejladue/errata.html) is pretty handy collection of errata for *Third Edition* through *Magic of Faerûn* (Aug. 2001), and if you're sifting through *Third Edition* books anyway, you can go in order using [this list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610).

Answer (score 1):

Use Polymorph (et al.) from the 3e PHB, noting there are clarifications, but not errata, [to it](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata). The reprints in the 3.5e PHB may be superfically different, but are fundamentally the same "become a monster manual entry" that later 3.5e era errata changed

Comment: Reading your answer, it's not clear to me why the 3.5e PHB spells and errata get mentioned. (Unless you mean it's the same spell that later ***3e*** era errata changed, or something..?) Could you clarify why you're mentioning that exactly? Consider also confirming whether there are no 3e era errata for polymorph, given you're recommending the raw PHB version.

Comment: In its description of the *polymorph other* and *self* spells, *Tome and Blood* says , "This version of the spell is now official and supersedes the version presented in the *Player’s Handbook*."