# Is there a way to get Decisive Strike with a non-Monk weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, weapons, monk, alternate-class-feature

I'm working on a Darth Vader build for a competition. To represent the light saber, I would really like to use mind blade (from the 3.0 Soulknife prestige class, which is actually pretty cool, especially compared to the 3.5 base class). However, the Monk ACF Decisive Strike would make a fantastic addition to the build, and this ACF replaces Flurry of Blows.

Problem is, Unorthodox Flurry and Whirling Steel Strike - either of which would make the mind blade a special monk weapon - both have "flurry of blows class feature" as a prerequisite, so I can't use them. My second thought was Shou Disciple, but it only lets you flurry with other weapons; it doesn't make them special monk weapons, and thus it wouldn't let you decisive strike with mind blade either. The Eberron Monk substitution levels give you Whirling Steel Strike as a bonus feat, which would normally obviate the need for the prerequisites... but explicitly still requires all prerequisites. There are also numerous classes that give you a "flurry" of some flavor, but none I've found so far are specifically a "flurry of blows" that would work as a monk-independent way of qualifying for one of the feats.

**So how about it? Is there a way to make a mind blade, short sword, or longsword* count as a monk special weapon that doesn't also require you to have Flurry of Blows?**

**Or a way to count as having the "Flurry of Blows class feature" to qualify for a feat?**

**Or for that matter, a way to get Decisive Strike without trading away Flurry of Blows?**

---

*The Soulknife prestige class (Psionics Handbook pg 113) says the mind blade is "identical to" a short sword until level 8, at which point it's "identical to" a longsword. As far as I'm concerned, that means any method that works for one of those also works for the mind blade. It also means longsword is the least preferable of the three.

Comment: This is for a Giant in the Playground optimization contest, so Dragon Magazine content is not preferred. That said, an answer is an answer. Just because I can't use it doesn't make it not interesting.

Comment: Eh, I think my question has a different enough focus from the other one, but since I got my answer anyway from a 3rd question I can't complain! (Disciple of the Eye PrC has "Flurry of Blows" as a class feature, unambiguously qualifying you for any of the feats that make the mind blade a monk special weapon that can be used w/ Decisive Strike.)

Answer (score 2):

Flowing Blade is a feat from the [“Blades of the Quori” Dragonshards web article](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebds/20050110a), and with it you treat a mind blade as a special monk weapon, allowing it to be used in a flurry of blows, and should qualify it for decisive strike as well.

> #### Flowing Blade [General]
>
> Your mind blade is an extension of your body and soul, and you wield it with the same grace as your foot or fist.
>
> **Prerequisite:** Ability to generate a mind blade, Weapon Focus (mind blade), flurry of blows class feature.
>
> **Benefit:** You can treat your mind blade as a special monk weapon so that you can perform a flurry of blows with it.
>
> **Special:** A kalashtar or Inspired monk can select this as a bonus feat at 2nd or 6th level, in addition to the normal options available at those levels. They must still meet all prerequisites for the feat.

Note however that it requires flurry of blows, which is a huge downer. Most DMs would likely let decisive strike qualify here, but RAW it does not. But you can get flurry of blows from other sources in order to qualify here.

As mentioned [in this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166647/4563), the Whirling Steel Strike feat from *Eberron Campaign Setting* will make longsword a special monk weapon, and Unorthodox Flurry from *Dragon Compendium* will do the same for your choice of light weapon (which could mean a short sword). Both feats, however, also require flurry of blows, and are therefore not terribly helpful here.

Comment: Credit to @HeyICanChan for [pointing this feat out to me recently](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166645/what-are-the-ways-to-add-new-weapon-allowances-to-decisive-strike-flurry-of-blow/166647#comment443723_166647), which is why I thought of it immediately.

Comment: @PoeticallyPsychotic You can get that elsewhere in order to qualify, and then decisive strike will benefit. I’ll add some ideas for getting it to the answer. Tashalatora, sadly, likely doesn’t work.

Comment: Sorry, I've been editing my comments as you're editing your answer and probably causing confusion.

Comment: @PoeticallyPsychotic That’s fine. I am still working on figuring out how best to get flurry of blows for this situation—proving more difficult than I originally thought. If nothing else, Shou disciple works, but that’s quite painful.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to track down two solutions to my own question so far. One is from Dragon Magazine, and thus not helpful to my personal problem, and the other is cheesy to the point that I'd prefer not to use it. Oh, and now a third one that's both.

In other words, the question remains open.

---

### The Cheesy

Okay, while I was typing up the question I thought of a workaround. However, it is *super* cheesy, so an alternative would be great.

The Symbiotic Creature template (Savage Species) gives you all the special attacks and special qualities of the host and guest. A quick look through the Monster Manuals suggests that all class features are either special attacks or special qualities. If one of them has Flurry of Blows, the other could have Decisive Strike (e.g. a Kobold Monk 1 as the guest and a Half-Ogre Monk 1 as the host).

Using this in the final build would be a last resort. (Although it *would* make an interesting way of representing General Grievous, with his humanoid mind controlling a robotic body...)

---

### The Dragon Magazine

Dragon Magazine 330 has several different "weapon schools"; alternate lists of special monk weapons. *Every single one of them* includes the short sword, I suspect for the sole purpose of taunting me.

---

### Both!

5 levels in the disappointing 3.5 Soulknife base class gives you Shape Mind Blade as a class feature. Then, Dragon Magazine 341 has the Reshape Mind Blade feat, which lets you add a new weapon shape to your repertoire, letting you choose something that's already a monk special weapon.

Main problem with this is that it's more than a little sketchy to use both the 3.0 unupdated Soulknife and the 3.5 updated one. I considered it acceptable before because there's already precedent for [prestige versions of base classes](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/prestigiousCharacterClasses.htm), but those aren't supposed to exist in the same campaign/universe as their base class counterparts. And it's *still* relying on Dragon Magazine content.