# Do the spells of the paladin's oaths works like cantrips?

Tags: spells, dungeons-and-dragons, paladin

When a paladin gets to the third level, it can choose an oath from the paladins oaths. This oath gives certain abilities and spells that act "naturally" for the oath. This means that it doesn't need to be prepared, while the other spells do need a certain preparation before hand, a paladin needs to have certain spell slots and they must think about the spells they can cast before sleep (that's the preparation).

But something remains unclear for me. Do the spells of the paladin's oath work like cantrips for wizards and mages? Does using one still consume a spell slot?

I am actually playing a Paladin in a campaign, and I think those spells don't work like that, but I am not sure of that.

Comment: What edition of D&D are you playing?

Comment: Hi Martin, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. I have made some minor edits regarding grammar, but please override my edits if I have changed the meaning of your question in any way. Please note that this question will likely be closed as unclear unless you can provide the edition of D&D, since different editions have different rules so giving an answer is impossible without knowing the edition. Thanks and happy gaming!

Comment: Martin, we still need to know what *edition* of D&D you're playing. Each edition has different rules so we can't answer this without knowing which edition's rules we're looking at. Please add a tag to indicate the edition; for example: [tag:dnd-5e], [tag:dnd-4e], [tag:dnd-3.5e], [tag:pathfinder], [tag:adnd], [tag:adnd-2e]? If you're unsure then please check out [this question here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135571/14878) to help you identify which edition of D&D you're playing.