# What are some essentials to get a first time DM for their campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm

My boyfriend has been playing D&D for a few years now but is going to be a first-time DM in his group's next campaign which will be starting late-December. I want to get him some Christmas gifts that will help him in his campaign but I know very little about D&D so I'm looking for some help! I was thinking of getting the "Dungeon Master's Guide: Core Rulebook" by the Wizards RPG Team but I'm hoping to get some feedback about whether this would be a good idea or not, as well as any other suggestions from avid players like you all! Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Hi sam, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Unfortunately this question will likely be closed as shopping questions are off-topic here. You might like to try one of our [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/48759) instead. Good luck! and good luck to him in his first game!

Comment: Hi Sam, please take a look at this [Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135571/35259) about which logos to look out for if/when you buy these books. I'd hate for you to buy some books, but then it turns out they're for the wrong edition of the game.

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, the only thing a DM *needs* to run a game is:

- Access to the [Dungeon Master's Guide](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/dungeon-masters-guide), the [Player's Handbook](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook), and the [Monster Manual](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/monster-manual)
- Dice
- Writing materials for note taking.

Honestly, there is [plenty more](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/catalog) they *could* get, but they're not essential.

Comment: I don't think you actually really need the DMG, PHB or MM to dm either!

Comment: He could get started with just the Starter Kit. It includes dice and everything.

Comment: And considering that he has been playing for years, the chances are high that he already has access to most of those

Comment: To add on to the dice, for playing Dungeons and Dragons, you need seven kinds of dice (each called a d[number], based on the amount of sides it has) - a d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20, and another d10 with two-digit numbers on it - this is used in combination with the other d10 to roll a d100.