# Im trying to learn how to play d&d and there is a question i can't figure out about attacking

Tags: damage

Assume my character is a level 1 fighter and I'm using a hand axe as my weapon. I read that fighters get  1d10 at level 1 and the hand axe uses 1d4. So what dice do i roll for my damage roll of my attack? I know I use 1d20 for the attack roll but what do i use foe the damage roll? Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: What *edition* of D&D are you asking about? If you're unsure then this question may be able to help: [How do I know which edition of Dungeons and Dragons (D&D) the books I'm looking at are for?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135571/14878)

Comment: There are between 8 and 20-odd variants of D&D, plus offshoot pojects, depending on what you count.

Comment: Have you tried asking your Dungeon Master about this?

Answer (score 6):

First, please note that there are many [editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135571/14878) of Dungeons & Dragons and they are all effectively more-or-less different games. So, please, tag your question with the correct edition (e.g. [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e)).

Fortunately, this question has the same answer in all the editions.

Fighters have 1d10 for *their* hit points - the amount of damage they can take when other creatures attack them.

The damage they do when they attack is dictated by the weapon they use. So the hand axe uses the same damage dice irrespective of if it's a fighter or a wizard using it. However, for the hand axe, in all major editions, the damage is 1d6 not 1d4.

Comment: "Fortunately, this question has the same answer in all the editions." Well, except for the editions where fighters don't get 1d10 HP and/or hand-axes don't do 1d6. In BECMI, for instance, fighters only got 1d8 HP, and it looks like hand-axes do 1d4 damage vs Large enemies in ADnD 1e.