# Does the bite of the wolf actually deal extra damage, or does it increase the base bite damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage, psionics, creature-size

The 1st-level psychic warrior power [***bite of the wolf***](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersAtoC.html#bite-of-the-wolf) [psychometabolism] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 80), in part, says

> If you are not a Medium creature, your bite attack’s base damage varies as follows: Fine 1d2, Diminutive 1d3, Tiny 1d4, Small 1d6, Large 2d6, Huge 2d8, Gargantuan 4d6, Colossal 6d6.
>
> Based on your psychic warrior level, your bite increases in ferocity as noted here: at 5th level your bite deals an extra 1d8 points of damage, at 10th level an extra 2d8, at 15th level an extra 3d8, and at 20th level an extra 4d8 points.

[Keeping in mind that the *Handbook* is quite early in the *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* life cycle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610) (Apr. 2004—only 4 months after *Complete Warrior*, for example), is the *extra damage* mentioned in the second paragraph actually extra damage as we now understand it—i.e. added after weapon damage and not multiplied on a critical hit—, so that, for example, a Large creature with its bite deals 2d6 + the creature's Strength modifier points of damage plus an extra +1d8 points of damage? Or is that so-called *extra damage*, like, code for increasing a Medium creature's *base* bite damage, so that, for example, a Large creature with its bite deals 4d6 + the creature's Strength modifier points of damage?

Or is neither reading of *bite of the wolf* correct, and I should determine its damage some totally different way?

---

***"Why do you ask?":** Well, the phrase* your bite increases in ferocity *isn't exactly a mechanical game term. Likewise, that extra 1d8 points of damage is* exactly *the same amount as a Medium creature deals with its* bite *power normally! Finally, it strikes me as strange that a psion 5 Fine creature's* bite of the wolf *power would deal 1d2 + the creature's Strength modifier points of damage plus an extra +1d8 points of damage instead of the much easier to determine 2d2 + the creature's Strength modifier. (While the former* would be *an increase in ferocity, it seems to me a* weird *increase in ferocity!) Anyway, the [war mind](http://dndsrd.net/psionicWarMind.html#war-mind) 5 giant that possesses this power and the* [expansion](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersDtoF.html#expansion) *power would much rather see itself—upon achieving Huge size—deal 4d8 + its Strength modifiers points of damage than 2d8 + its Strength modifiers points of damage plus an extra +1d8 points of damage!*

*I'm certain that this was all hashed out on the Wizards of the Coast forums back in the day and therefore that I'm dreadfully late to the party, but psionics have never been my thing.*

Answer (score 3):

### Your basic bite attack is one thing and the extra damage another.

Reading the power, I emphasized these 2 parts so you can understand the point here:

> If you are not a Medium creature, **your bite attack’s base damage** varies as follows: Fine 1d2, Diminutive 1d3, Tiny 1d4, Small 1d6, Large 2d6, Huge 2d8, Gargantuan 4d6, Colossal 6d6.
>
> Based on your psychic warrior level, your bite increases in ferocity as noted here: at 5th level **your bite deals an extra 1d8 points of damage**, at 10th level an extra 2d8, at 15th level an extra 3d8, and at 20th level an extra 4d8 points.

This power clearly separates your *"bite attacks base damage"* and extra damage. It never says its bite damage increases, but says that it *"deals an extra 1d8 points of damage"*; not extra dice based on your size, nor gives a new damage to your bite attack, only extra d8s of damage.

I'll explain this for a medium character, use the appropriate dice for each size. Your one bite attack per round causes 1d8 points of damage and receive an extra damage that increases by 1d8 at levels 5, 10, 15 and 20.

For example, at level 10, your bite attack you will cause 1d8+Strength+2d8 damage in a normal hit and 2d8+2xStrength+2d8 in a critical hit. While not being the best result, remember that is a level 1 power that evolves alone without expending extra PP that allows you to use it as secondary natural attack without using your hands.

Comment: It's cool if this's all you got, but it's all I got, too. I was really hoping for something— *anything* — beyond *It's extra damage because it says it's says extra damage*, like a sample character employing the power or some noted authority doubly clarifying that that's accurate. (I mean, making the Fine psychic warrior 5's ferocity as awesomely fearsome as the Colossal psychic warrior 5's ferocity seems an unusual way to scale the power!)

Comment: Excluding the fact that it is how my psionic enthusiast player explained it to me at the time and a [2009 build](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?127217-Psychic-Warrior-Wildman-build-3-5) that used it this way, I have nothing more since WotC forums are no longer around.

Answer (score 0):

From the SRD "You gain one bite attack each round, instead of or in addition to any other attacks you have, that deals 1d8 points of damage (assuming you are a Medium creature) when it hits."

To me, that would mean that a medium human would grow a wolf's muzzle and do 1d8 damage with it, +1d8 extra damage per 5 levels

BUT a fine character would grow a wee little muzzle and do 1d2 damage +1d2 extra damage per 5 levels.

and a Huge Giant would bite for 2d8 base +2d8 extra per 5 levels...