# Are there any updates to the DMG that describe magic item activation in the format presented in magic item compendium?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Straightforward self explanatory question really as described in the title. Magic Item Compendium presents activating magic items in this manner [Action Type] (type of action) as per page 220. Is anyone aware of an update to the DMG that describes magic items presented therein in the same format?

Take for example a RING OF LIGHTNING FLASHES page 125 of Magic Item Compendium we can see that the activation is [Swift] (mental) which produces a comparable spell effect that results in direct damage. Whereas a reading of a RING OF ELEMENTAL COMMAND (Fire) page 231 DMG any of the following  Burning hands, Flaming sphere, Wall of fire or Flame strike requires a standard action to activate. This kind of disparity in action economy seems a little odd to me. Just to be clear I understand that Swift and Immediate actions were introduced after the DMG was published, hence the question.

Comment: Is there inspiration for this question? (Using particular magic items from the *DMG* that possess controversial or unclear activation times would serve to contextualize the issue and demonstrate why the question's important.)

Comment: Yes see above for edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can say with some confidence as a fan with fairly extensive knowledge of the material available for the game (q.v. [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610)) that nothing published by Wizards of the Coast updates the magic items from the *Dungeon Master's Guide* to the format found in the *Magic Item Compendium.*

While later writers would—through accident or design—deviate from the guidelines established by the *DMG* by raising or lowering prices or changing the slots of items (examples of which can be found by comparing items in the *DMG* to similar items in the *MIC*), to my knowledge there was never any effort made by Wizards of the Coast to formally or informally update or change the *DMG*'s magic items to match or become equivalent to the magic items found in the *MIC*. (Sort of like how the *Monster Manual* remains unchanged despite later material using a much different format for monsters' stat blocks.)

In short, you and and I and everyone else are stuck with the *DMG*'s items as-is, no matter how baffling they sometimes are.

---

***Note:*** To be fair to the [ring of fire elemental command](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-elemental-command) *and the similar* rings, *they're legacy items dating back at least to 1977 that have always had a host of weird powers. I suspect they were in 2000 priced partially by eyeball and only briefly reviewed for the* 3.5 *revision because no one wanted them, folks having realized that the* rings' *abilities were silly for what had been established as their prices. Also, the comparison to the* ring of lightning *flashes may be a little difficult: while the* ring of lightning flashes *wins in the action economy department, it has 3 charges per day, and the game has always been wary of—and placed a perhaps* too *expensive premium on—unlimited-use effects, like the* burning hands *feature of the* ring of fire elemental command.

Comment: That publication list in date order is really useful thanks. Bookmarked for referral.