# What are the official abbreviations or short forms of the 3rd edition of the D&D books?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, books

What are the official abbreviations or short forms of the titles of 3rd edition of the D&D books? There appear to be a few different styles or forms online.

Comment: (Abbreviations for each book are also listed parenthetically after each title in [this answer.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The Consolidated Lists published by WotC include an extensive list of officially defined abbreviations all in one place:

```
Product Key
AE      Arms and Equipment Guide
BFK     Barrow of the Forgotten King
BB      Bastion of Broken Souls
BC      Book of Challenges: Dungeon Rooms, Puzzles, and Traps
BE      Book of Exalted Deeds
BV      Book of Vile Darkness
CR      Champions of Ruin
CV      Champions of Valor
CiP     City of Peril
CSW     City of Splendors: Waterdeep
CSQ     City of the Spider Queen
Ci      Cityscape
CAd     Complete Adventurer
CAr     Complete Arcane
CC      Complete Champion
CD      Complete Divine
CM      Complete Mage
CP      Complete Psionic
CS      Complete Scoundrel
CW      Complete Warrior
Co      Cormyr: The Tearing of the Weave
DG      D&D Gazetteer
DH      Deep Horizon
DF      Defenders of the Faith: A Guidebook to Clerics and Paladins
DD      Deities and Demigods
Dr      Draconomicon
DM      Dragon Magic
Dra     Dragonmarked
DCS     Dragonlance Campaign Setting
DrF     Dragons of Faerûn
DrU     Drow of the Underdark
DMG     Dungeon Master's Guide v.3.5
DMG2    Dungeon Master's Guide II
Du      Dungeonscape
ECS     Eberron Campaign Setting
EA      Enemies and Allies
EL      Epic Level Handbook
EE      Exemplars of Evil
XPH     Expanded Psionics Handbook
Rav     Expedition to Castle Ravenloft
EDP     Expedition to the Demonweb Pits
ERG     Expedition to the Ruins of Greyhawk
EU      Expedition to Undermountain
EH      Explorer's Handbook
ELQ     Eyes of the Lich Queen
FP      Faiths & Pantheons
FE      Faiths of Eberron
FLFD    Fantastic Locations: Fane of the Drow
FLFR    Fantastic Locations: Fields of Ruin
FLHP    Fantastic Locations: Hellspike Prison
FF      Fiend Folio
FCI     Fiendish Codex I: Hordes of the Abyss
FCI     Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells
Fo      Forge of Fury, The
FW      Forge of War, The
FRCS    Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting
FY      Fortress of the Yuan-Ti
Fr      Frostburn
Gh      Ghostwalk
GHR     Grand History of the Realms
GC      Grasp of the Emerald Claw
HN      Heart of Nightfang Spire
HBG     Hero Builder's Guidebook
HB      Heroes of Battle
HH      Heroes of Horror
LM      Libris Mortis: The Book of the Dead
LG      Living Greyhawk Gazetteer
LF      Lord of the Iron Fortress
LD      Lords of Darkness
LoM     Lords of Madness
LE      Lost Empires of Faerûn
MIC     Magic Item Compendium
MoE     Magic of Eberron
Mag     Magic of Faerûn
MoI     Magic of Incarnum
MP      Manual of the Planes
MW      Masters of the Wild: A Guidebook to Barbarians, Druids, and Rangers
MH      Miniatures Handbook
Mon     Monster Compendium: Monsters of Faerûn
MM5     Monster Manual V
MM4     Monster Manual IV
MM3     Monster Manual III
MM2     Monster Manual II
MM      Monster Manual v.3.5
Mys     Mysteries of the Moonsea
OA      Oriental Adventures
PlH     Planar Handbook
PE      Player's Guide to Eberron
PG      Player's Guide to Faerûn
PH      Player's Handbook v.3.5
PH2     Player's Handbook II
PF      Power of Faerûn
RD      Races of Destiny
RE      Races of Eberron
Rac     Races of Faerûn
RS      Races of Stone
RDr     Races of the Dragon
RW      Races of the Wild
RH      Red Hand of Doom
RT      Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil
Sa      Sandstorm
SS      Savage Species
SoS     Secrets of Sarlona
SX      Secrets of Xen'drik
SK      Serpent Kingdoms
SSL     Shadowdale: The Scouring of the Land
SL      Shadows of the Last War
Sh      Sharn: City of Towers
ShG     The Shattered Gates of Slaughtergarde
ShS     Shining South
SM      Silver Marches
SiS     Sinister Spire, The
SaS     Song and Silence: A Guidebook to Bards and Rogues
SG      Sons of Gruumsh
SD      Speaker in Dreams, The
StS     Standing Stone, The
Sto     Stormwrack
SB      Stronghold Builder's Guidebook
SC      Sunless Citadel, The
SpC     Spell Compendium
SF      Sword and Fist: A Guidebook to Monks and Fighters
TB      Tome and Blood: A Guidebook to Wizards and Sorcerers
ToB     Tome of Battle: The Book of Nine Swords
TM      Tome of Magic
Una     Unapproachable East
Und     Underdark
UA      Unearthed Arcana
VGD     Voyage of the Golden Dragon
WB      Whispers of the Vampire's Blade
```

Not all communities or sites use the correct official designations, having developed their own short forms, so please be aware of that fact in your communications.

Comment: Your table alignment isn’t quite perfect there. I tried replacing this with LaTeX, but apparently it’s too long, overwhelms the MathJax buffer. It may also be worth noting that these are not the most commonly-used abbreviations in the community.

Comment: How's that? Looks good in my device, but that's not always reliable.

Comment: It looks good for me.

Comment: "Not all communities or sites use the correct official designations" seems like a bit of an understatement. The Player's Handbook is the most obvious one – I don't think I've ever seen someone use anything other than PHB for that – but scanning over the list there are plenty of others that I almost always see abbreviated in other ways, starting with the very first one. I didn't even know there *was* an official list of abbreviations before this.

Comment: I've also used the incorrect abbreviations prior to this question occurring to me. I have long been aware of this list of abbreviations (being one whi heavily uses the consolidated lists) but I had never paid close attention to the differences before now. For the first, perhaps they were avoiding being confused with the company AEG? But that doesn't answer for the PH versus PHB... unless someone is into chemistry jokes at WotC....

Comment: @nijineko These abbreviations seem to have been designed to be as short as possible, only adding more letters when absolutely forced to by existing products already claiming the two-letter abbreviation. The community abbreviations instead focus more on making it clear what product is being referred to, even if it takes an extra letter or two. The community also simply *doesn’t* abbreviate a lot of these products, because they’re just too obscure to refer to by anything but full title and expect readers to understand.

Comment: Also, I just noticed you have “FCI” for both *Fiendish Codex I* and *Fiendish Codex II*; is that mistake in the original?

Comment: @KRyan excellent point! I also find that when comparing, I prefer the community abbreviations in some cases over the apparently official ones. I will check the original list regarding that possible error. As I simply copy pasted, it likely is in the original, lol.

Comment: It appears to be in the original.... sigh. I'm giving you a +1 for good logic and valid common sense in your answer, even though I do not feel it can be ethically selected as the "right" answer due to official versus unofficial, despite your very valid points. I'm even ignoring how I feel about unsolicited extra information in view of your excellent points, this once.

Answer (score 10):

I have made an attempt to pair the official abbreviations with those actually used by the community. For example, *Player’s Handbook* is universally abbreviated as PHB—but the official abbreviation is PH. If I saw PH, I would sooner think *Planar Handbook* (usually, and also officially, PlH) than *Player’s Handbook*. Also, officially, SC refers to *The Sunless Citadel*—which I don’t think I have ever heard of. Meanwhile, SC is one of the most commonly-used abbreviations in the game—for *Spell Compendium*. I have seen the official abbreviation, SpC, used for it, but it’s almost-always SC. Someone using SC to refer to *The Sunless Citadel* is quite simply wrong.

Note that a whole lot of books simply *aren’t* abbreviated by the community, usually because they’re too obscure to expect anyone to recognize in abbreviation. A few major books, though, simply don’t abbreviate neatly—the “Outside” books, *Cityscape*, *Dungeonscape*, *Frostburn*, *Sandstorm*, and *Stormwrack* fall in this category, particularly *Dungeonscape* which I can’t honestly remember ever seeing abbreviated. Anyway, stuff that doesn’t get abbreviated, I’ve marked —. Stuff that rarely gets abbreviated but I have seen, that gets a ¹, and I have included a couple other footnotes at the bottom as well.

| Product | Official | Community |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Arms and Equipment Guide* | AE | A&EG |
| *Barrow of the Forgotten King* | BFK | — |
| *Bastion of Broken Souls* | BB | BoBS︎︎¹ |
| *Book of Challenges* | BC | — |
| *Book of Exalted Deeds* | BE | BoED |
| *Book of Vile Darkness* | BV | BoVD |
| *Champions of Ruin* | CR | CoR |
| *Champions of Valor* | CV | CoV |
| *City of Peril* | CiP | — |
| *City of Splendors: Waterdeep* | CSW | CoS︎︎¹ |
| *City of the Spider Queen* | CSQ | — |
| *Cityscape* | Ci | City︎︎¹ |
| *Complete Adventurer* | CAd | CAdv |
| *Complete Arcane* | CAr | CArc |
| *Complete Champion* | CC | CCh or CChamp |
| *Complete Divine* | CD | CDiv |
| *Complete Mage* | CM | CMag or CMage |
| *Complete Psionic* | CP | CPsi |
| *Complete Scoundrel* | CS | CSc or CSco |
| *Complete Warrior* | CW | CW or CWar |
| *Cormyr: The Tearing of the Weave* | Co | — |
| *D&D Gazetteer* | DG | — |
| *Deep Horizon* | DH | — |
| *Defenders of the Faith* | DF | DotF |
| *Deities and Demigods* | DD | D&DG |
| *Draconomicon* | Dr | Dr or Drac |
| *Dragon Magic* | DM | DM |
| *Dragonlance Campaign Setting* | DCS | DCS or DrCS or DLCS |
| *Dragonmarked* | Dra | — |
| *Dragons of Faerûn* | DrF | DoF |
| *Drow of the Underdark* | DrU | DotU |
| *Dungeon Master's Guide II* | DMG2 | DMG2 |
| *Dungeon Master's Guide v.3.5* | DMG | DMG |
| *Dungeonscape* | Du | — |
| *Eberron Campaign Setting* | ECS | EbCS |
| *Enemies and Allies* | EA | — |
| *Epic Level Handbook* | EL | ELH |
| *Exemplars of Evil* | EE | EoE︎︎¹ |
| *Expanded Psionics Handbook* | XPH | XPH |
| *Expedition to Castle Ravenloft* | Rav | — |
| *Expedition to the Demonweb Pits* | EDP | — |
| *Expedition to the Ruins of Greyhawk* | ERG | — |
| *Expedition to Undermountain* | EU | — |
| *Explorer's Handbook* | EH | — |
| *Eyes of the Lich Queen* | ELQ | — |
| *Faiths & Pantheons* | FP | F&P︎︎¹ |
| *Faiths of Eberron* | FE | FoE |
| *Fantastic Locations: Fane of the Drow* | FLFD | — |
| *Fantastic Locations: Fields of Ruin* | FLFR | — |
| *Fantastic Locations: Hellspike Prison* | FLHP | — |
| *Fiend Folio* | FF | FF |
| *Fiendish Codex I: Hordes of the Abyss* | FCI | FC1 |
| *Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells* | FCI︎︎² | FC2 |
| *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* | FRCS | FRCS |
| *Fortress of the Yuan-Ti* | FY | — |
| *Frostburn* | Fr | Frost︎︎¹ |
| *Ghostwalk* | Gh | Gh︎︎¹ |
| *Grand History of the Realms* | GHR | — |
| *Grasp of the Emerald Claw* | GC | — |
| *Heart of Nightfang Spire* | HN | — |
| *Hero Builder's Guidebook* | HBG | — |
| *Heroes of Battle* | HB | HoB |
| *Heroes of Horror* | HH | HoH |
| *Libris Mortis: The Book of the Dead* | LM | LM |
| *Living Greyhawk Gazetteer* | LG | — |
| *Lord of the Iron Fortress* | LF | — |
| *Lords of Darkness* | LD | — |
| *Lords of Madness* | LoM | LoM |
| *Lost Empires of Faerûn* | LE | LEoF |
| *Magic Item Compendium* | MIC | MIC |
| *Magic of Eberron* | MoE | MoE |
| *Magic of Faerûn* | Mag | MoF︎︎³ |
| *Magic of Incarnum* | MoI | MoI |
| *Manual of the Planes* | MP | MotP |
| *Masters of the Wild* | MW | MotW |
| *Miniatures Handbook* | MH | MH |
| *Monster Manual v.3.5* | MM | MM |
| *Monster Manual II* | MM2 | MM2 |
| *Monster Manual III* | MM3 | MM3 |
| *Monster Manual IV* | MM4 | MM4 |
| *Monster Manual V* | MM5 | MM5 |
| *Monsters of Faerûn* | Mon | MoF︎¹ ³ |
| *Mysteries of the Moonsea* | Mys | — |
| *Oriental Adventures* | OA | OA |
| *Planar Handbook* | PlH | PlH |
| *Player’s Guide to Eberron* | PE | PGtE |
| *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* | PG | PGtF |
| *Player’s Handbook v.3.5* | PH | PHB |
| *Player’s Handbook II* | PH2 | PHB2 |
| *Power of Faerûn* | PF | PoF |
| *Races of Destiny* | RD | RoD |
| *Races of Eberron* | RE | RoE |
| *Races of Faerûn* | Rac | RoF |
| *Races of Stone* | RS | RoS |
| *Races of the Dragon* | RDr | RotD |
| *Races of the Wild* | RW | RotW |
| *Red Hand of Doom* | RH | RHoD |
| *Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil* | RT | — |
| *Sandstorm* | Sa | Sand︎︎¹ |
| *Savage Species* | SS | SS |
| *Secrets of Sarlona* | SoS | SoS |
| *Secrets of Xen’drik* | SX | SoX |
| *Serpent Kingdoms* | SK | SK︎︎¹ |
| *Shadowdale: The Scouring of the Land* | SSL | — |
| *Shadows of the Last War* | SL | — |
| *Sharn: City of Towers* | Sh | — |
| *Shining South* | ShS | ShS |
| *Silver Marches* | SM | — |
| *Song and Silence* | SaS | S&S |
| *Sons of Gruumsh* | SG | — |
| *Spell Compendium* | SpC | SC︎︎⁴ |
| *Stormwrack* | Sto | Storm︎︎¹ |
| *Stronghold Builder's Guidebook* | SB | SBG |
| *Sword and Fist* | SF | S&F |
| *The Forge of Fury* | Fo | — |
| *The Forge of War* | FW | — |
| *The Shattered Gates of Slaughtergarde* | ShG | — |
| *The Sinister Spire* | SiS | — |
| *The Speaker in Dreams* | SD | — |
| *The Standing Stone* | StS | — |
| *The Sunless Citadel* | SC⁴ | — |
| *Tome and Blood* | TB | T&B |
| *Tome of Battle* | ToB | ToB |
| *Tome of Magic* | TM | ToM |
| *Unapproachable East* | Una | Una |
| *Underdark* | Und | Und |
| *Unearthed Arcana* | UA | UA |
| *Voyage of the Golden Dragon* | VGD | — |
| *Whispers of the Vampire's Blade* | WB | — |

1. <sub>Rare. These books are either rarely discussed, or simply rarely abbreviated.</sub>
2. <sub>Some sources have “FCI” for *Fiendish Codex II*, some have “FCII,” and some even have “FC2,” though these last also have “FC1” for *Fiendish Codex I*. I cannot find the official statement—though if it does have “FCI” that would be an error, since FCI is *Fiendish Codex I*. But an error is possible, after all.</sub>
3. <sub>Note that the “fan abbreviations” for *Magic of Faerûn* and *Monsters of Faerûn* conflict. MoF usually means *Magic of Faerûn*; *Monsters of Faerûn* is rarely discussed. But I have seen the abbreviation.</sub>
4. <sub>Note that the official abbreviation, SC, for *The Sunless Citadel*—which is extremely obscure—conflicts with the nigh-universally-used fan abbreviation for *Spell Compendium*, one of the most frequenly-cited books in the game. A strong case in point for **not** using the official abbreviations.</sub>

Comment: While I definitely agree that the community derived abbreviations are much more universally used, I cannot agree that they are "right". Official is official (no matter how stupid) and thus is automatically right, sad as that may be and rife with errors like the rest of the game. <humor>now if only there was an Errata or FAQ documented for the lists...</humor> lol. Thank you for the very useful comparison!

Comment: Not abbreviations, but the Sandstorm et al. books are also called "It's hot outside" (Sa), "it's cold outside" (Fr), "it's wet outside" (Sto), "it's crowded outside" (Ci) and ..."it's not outside" (Du)