# What are all of the armors and shields that are legal in 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, armor, shield

I want a complete list of every 3.5e-legal type of armor and shield published by Wizards of the Coast, or in *Dragon* or *Dungeon* magazine. (To be clear, I mean base type of armor or shield, not every possible material or magical enhancement they might receive.) I have the Crystal Keep index, which is great, but I have known the Crystal Keep indices to be missing things in the past, so I don’t feel confident that its list of armors and shields is complete, either.

Obviously, this is an enormous amount of material to comb through, but I don’t expect the amount of material actually on the list to be all that large: Crystal Keep’s list of armors and shields through October 1, 2007 contains about 50 separate entries,¹ and I expect that it’s *almost* complete, so a thorough list won’t be much larger. Furthermore, almost all of the entries come from *Player’s Handbook* or *Races of Stone*, which I know about, so the list doesn’t need to contain those. (Really, a list of *sources* that add new armors or shields *not mentioned in the Crystal Keep index* would be sufficient for my purposes, but that feels a little too specific for a Stack question.)

1. <sub>The index actually has about 100 entries, but there are a ton of repeats just in different standard materials, e.g. the heavy shield appears 5 times, in bronze, darkwood, mithral, wood, and steel).</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a lot of material. A key to abbreviations can be found in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/8610). Although some of the armors below are created from special materials (e.g. the mithral chain shirt), the game saw fit to provide those armors with their own statistics separately. Sometimes these statistics were in addition to providing how those statistics were derived (e.g. the special material [mithral](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#mithral) (*DMG* 284)) and sometimes not (e.g. the shadow silk armors (*TM* 155)).

### Unique armors compatible with the feat Armor Proficiency (light) (*PH* 89), from lowest armor bonus to highest

- mud armor (*Rac* 157) (0 gp; 8 lbs.)
- wicker (*AE* 15, 17) (1 gp; 5 lbs.)
- padded (*PH* 123, 125) (5 gp; 10 lbs.)
- retarius armor (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 116) (10 gp; 5 lbs.)
- samnite armor (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 116) (10 gp; 10 lbs.)
- dueling cloak (*Dragon* #335 77) (15 gp; 3 lbs.)
- silk swathes (*Sa* 99) (400 gp; 6 lbs.)
- thistledown padded (*RW* 168) (405 gp; 5 lbs.)
- leafweave padded (*RW* 168) (745 gp; 8 lbs.)
- bondleaf wrap (*AE* 14, 15) (1,000 gp; 2 lbs.)
- shadow silk padded (*TM* 155) (1,500 gp; 2.5 lbs.)
- bark (*Dragon* #319 42) (5 gp; 15 lbs.)
- leather (*PH* 123, 125) (10 gp; 15 lbs.)
- cord (*Sto* 106) (15 gp; 15 lbs.)
- thracian armor (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 116) (15 gp; 15 lbs.)
- chitin armor (*SX* 136) (20 gp; 10 lbs.)
- vine (*SX* 136) (80 gp; 15 lbs.)
- chameleon leather (*SK* 148) (360 gp; 15 lbs.)
- leafweave (*ECS* 120) (750 gp; 15 lbs.)
- leafweave leather (*RW* 168) (750 gp; 9 lbs.)
- feather cloak (*Sa* 99) (1,000 gp; 3 lbs.)
- nightscale (*Und* 66) (1,000 gp; 3 lbs.)
- shadow silk leather (*TM* 155) (1,750 gp; 4 lbs.)
- wood (*Dragon* #319 42, 43) (15 gp; 15 lbs.)
- bone (*Dragon* #319 42) (20 gp; 20 lbs.)
- ashigaru armor (*OA* 75, 76) (25 gp; 20 lbs.)
- studded leather (*PH* 123, 126) (25 gp; 20 lbs.)
- leather scale (*Dragon* #319 42, 43) (35 gp; 20 lbs.)
- secutor armor (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 116) (40 gp; 30 lbs.)
- hooked armor (*PlH* 69, 70) (65 gp; 20 lbs.)
- chitine web (*Und* 66) (75 gp; 10 lbs.)
- sharkskin (*Sto* 106) (85 gp; 15 lbs.)
- twisted silk (*Dragon* #348 87) (400 gp; 15 lbs.)
- gnome workman’s leather (Realms Personalities Web column ["Nadul DaRoni"](http://rpg.nobl.ca/archive.php?x=dnd/rp/20040114a)) (450 gp; 18 lbs.)
- wildwood chain shirt (*RW* 168) (500 gp; 19 lbs.)
- studded impact (*MoE* 138–9) (765 gp; 20 lbs.)
- shadow silk hide (*TM* 155) (2,500 gp; 5.5 lbs.)
- sectioned armor (fully reduced) (*PlH* 69, 70) (3,000 gp; 25 lbs.)
- silk armor (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 116) (5,000 gp; 15 lbs.)
- chain shirt (*PH* 123, 124) (100 gp; 25 lbs.)
- resin suit (*FF* 110) (250 gp; 20 lbs.)
- dreamhide (*SX* 136) (700 gp; 20 lbs.)
- mithral chain shirt (*RW* 168) (1,100 gp; 12.5 lbs.)
- mithral shirt (*DMG* 220) (1,100 gp; 10 lbs.)
- mithral scale mail (*RW* 168) (4,050 gp; 15 lbs.)
- moon-ivy (*AE* 15, 16) (16,000 gp; 5 lbs.)
- darkleaf breastplate (*ECS* 120) (2,450 gp; 30 lbs.)
- elven chain (*DMG* 220) (4,150 gp; 20 lbs.)
- mithral chain mail (*RW* 168) (4,150 gp; 20 lbs.)
- mithral breastplate (*RW* 168) (4,200 gp  15 lbs.)

### Unique armors compatible with the feat Armor Proficiency (medium) (*PH* 89), from lowest armor bonus to highest

- hide (*PH* 123) (15 gp; 25 lbs.)
- shell (*Sto* 106) (25 gp; 20 lbs.)
- thunderhide armor (*SK* 148) (25 gp; 25 lbs.)
- tentacled hide (*Und* 66, 67) (315 gp; 30 lbs.)
- wildwood scale mail (*RW* 168) (400 gp; 22.5 lbs.)
- leafweave hide (*RW* 168) (755 gp; 20 lbs.)
- grimorian hide armor (*Dragon* #274 101) (15 gp; 30 lbs.)
- brigandine (*AE* 14, 15) (30 gp; 40 lbs.)
- dhenuka (*OA* 75, 76) (30 gp; 25 lbs.)
- partial armor (*OA* 76, 77) (50 gp; 35 lbs.)
- scale mail (*PH* 123) (50 gp; 30 lbs.)
- chitin (*Sto* 106) (75 gp; 20 lbs.)
- ring (AE 15, 17) (75 gp; 35 lbs.)
- beaded armor (*Polyhedron* #159 32) (80 gp; 27 lbs.)
- bronze breastplate (*Dragon* #319 42) (200 gp; 30 lbs.)
- scorpion breastplate (*SX* 136) (300 gp; 20 lbs.)
- wildwood chainmail (*RW* 168) (600 gp; 30 lbs.)
- wildwood breastplate (*RW* 168) (700 gp; 22.5 lbs.)
- chain mail (*PH* 123) (150 gp; 40 lbs.)
- lamellar (*AE* 15) (150 gp; 35 lbs.)
- shell armor (*Mys* 78) (150 gp; 40 lbs.)
- breastplate (*PH* 123) (200 gp; 30 lbs.
- lead-lined breastplate (*Dragon* #348 87) (200 gp; 35 lbs.)
- Thurkasian breastplate (*Gh* 42) (250 gp; 30 lbs.)
- chitin breastplate (*RDr* 121–2) (700 gp; 30 lbs.)
- serpentscale mail (*SK* 148) (800 gp; 25 lbs.)
- chain impact (*MoE* 138–9) (1,290 gp; 40 lbs.)
- sectioned armor (partially reduced) (*PlH* 69, 70) (3,000 gp; 25 lbs.)
- adamatine breastplate (*DMG* 219) (10,200 gp; 30 lbs.)
- darkleaf banded mail (*ECS* 120) (3,250 gp; 35 lbs.)
- mithral splint mail (*RW* 168) (9,200 gp; 22.5 lbs.)
- mithral banded mail (*RW* 168) (9,250 gp; 17.5 lbs.)
- living coral (*Sto* 106) (16,000 gp; 30 lbs.)
- mithral half-plate (*RW* 168) (9,600 gp; 25 lbs.)
- mithral full plate (*RW* 168) (10,500 gp; 25 lbs.)

### Unique armors compatible with the feat Armor Proficiency (heavy) (*PH* 89), from lowest armor bonus to highest

- chitin (*Dragon* #319 42, 43) (100 gp; 35 lbs.)
- giant patchwork (*SX* 136) (100 gp; 50 lbs.)
- stonemail (*Und* 66, 67) (180 gp; 35 lbs.)
- splint mail (*PH* 123, 126) (200 gp; 45 lbs.)
- coral (*AE* 15) (225 gp; 40 lbs.)
- banded mail (*PH* 123, 124) (250 gp; 35 lbs.)
- bronze half-plate (*Dragon* #319 42) (600 gp; 50 lbs.)
- stone plate (*RS* 158) (750 gp; 35 lbs.)
- half-plate (*PH* 123, 125) (600 gp; 50 lbs.)
- great armor (*OA* 75, 76) (1,000 gp; 45 lbs.)
- chitin half-plate (*RDr* 121–2) (1,500 gp; 50 lbs.)
- war chitin (*SX* 136) (1,500 gp; 40 lbs.)
- half-plate impact (*MoE* 138–9) (2,450 gp; 50 lbs.)
- full plate (*PH* 123, 124) (1,500 gp; 50 lbs.)
- feeler plate (*Und* 66) (2,500 gp; 65 lbs.)
- sectioned armor (full) (*PlH* 69, 70) (3,000 gp; 60 lbs.)
- chitin full plate (*RDr* 121–2) (3,300 gp; 50 lbs.)
- dragonhide plate (*DMG* 220) (3,300 gp; 50 lbs.)
- dwarven plate (*DMG* 220) (16,500 gp; 50 lbs.)
- dwarven stone (*AE* 15, 17) (1,750 gp; 80 lbs.)
- dendritic crystal (*Rac* 157–8) (2,000 gp; 60 lbs.)
- heavy plate (*RS* 155, 158) (2,000 gp; 100 lbs.)
- mechanus gear (*PlH* 69, 70) (1,750 gp; 75 lbs.)
- thaalud stone armor (*An* 108) (2,800 gp; 180 lbs.)

### Unique light, medium, then heavy exotic armors, each from lowest armor bonus to highest, compatible with the feat Exotic Armor Proficiency (*SSL* 149)

**Exotic Light Armors**

- gnome twist cloth (*RS* 158, 159) (150 gp; 5 lbs.)
- spidersilk armor (*Und* 66, *SSL* 149) (750 gp; 5 lbs.)
- mammoth leather (*RS* 157, 158) (45 gp; 30 lbs.)

**Exotic Medium Armors**

- interlocking scale (RS 156–7, 158) (250 gp; 30 lbs.)
- tumbler’s breastpate (RS 158–9) (450 gp; 30 lbs.)

**Exotic Heavy Armors**

- interlocking plate (RS 155–6, 158) (1,750 gp; 50 lbs.)
- battle plate (*RS* 155, 158) (2,500 gp; 125 lbs.)
- mountain plate (*RS* 157, 158) (3,250 gp; 225 lbs.)

By way of trivia, the feat **Exotic Armor Proficiency** originally appeared in ***Underdark*** (Oct. 2003) (25) where it wasn't a fighter bonus feat, then in ***Races of Stone*** (Aug. 2004) (139) where it was a fighter bonus feat, then in ***Shadowdale: The Scouring of the Land*** (July 2007) where it was, once more and finally, *not* a fighter bonus feat. I can almost guarantee that your game will not be harmed if you house rule that the Exotic Armor Proficiency feat is a fighter bonus feat, though. Also, so you know, the feat **Dwarven Armor Proficiency** (*RS* 138) covers battle plate, interlocking plate, interlocking scale, and mountain plate; it is a fighter bonus feat.

### Unique shields compatible with the feat Shield Proficiency (*PH* 100), from lowest shield bonus to AC to highest

- kappa shell (*OA* 76) (30 gp; 20 lbs.)
- buckler (*PH* 123, 124) (15 gp; 5 lbs.)
- dastana (*AE* 15) (25 gp; 5 lbs.)
- diamond shield (*DrF* 136) (20 gp; 6 lbs.)
- grasping shield (*Rac* 157, 158) (50 gp; 11 lbs.)
- light bronze shield (*Dragon* #319 42, 43) (9 gp; 6 lbs.)
- light steel shield (*PH* 123, 125) (9 gp; 6 lbs.)
- light wooden shield (*PH* 123, 125) (3 gp; 5 lbs.)
- stiletto shield (*AE* 15, 17) (30 gp; 10 lbs.)
- tessen (*OA* 76, 77) (12 gp; 1 lb.)
- beetle buckler (*Dragon* #319 32–3) (6,600 gp; 5 lbs.)
- heavy bronze shield (*Dragon* #319 42, 43) (20 gp; 15 lbs.)
- heavy steel shield (*PH* 123, 125) (20 gp; 15 lbs.)
- heavy wooden shield (*PH* 123, 125) (7 gp; 10 lbs.)
- hide shield (*Sa* 99) (50 gp; 30 lbs.)

### Unique shields compatible with the feat Tower Shield Proficiency (*PH* 100) alphabetically

- chitin tower shield (*RDr* 121–2) (360 gp; 45 lbs.)
- steel tower shield (*RS* 158) (75 gp; 100 lbs.)
- tower shield (*PH* 123) (30 gp; 45 lbs.)

### Unique shields, each from lowest shield bonus to AC to highest, compatible with the feat Exotic Shield Proficiency (*RS* 139)

- gnome battle cloak (*RS* 158) (5 gp; 1 lb.)
- gauntlet shield (*RS* 158) (50 gp; 20 lbs.)
- rider’s shield (*RS* 158) (75 gp; 15 lbs.)
- extreme wooden shield (*RS* 157–8) (10 gp; 15 lbs.)
- extreme steel shield (*RS* 157–8) (30 gp; 25 lbs.)

Comment: Amazing, perfect, and appreciated.

Comment: I don't feel so strange anymore that I dissected the complete 5e MM. :D

Comment: Rather strange that the mithral breastplate is strictly better than the chainmail, but the difference in price is a mere 50 GP.

Comment: @J.Mini In many cases, you'll find that if you can pay just a *little* more you can get something strictly better—especially at the low end. (Or is that a subtle way of saying that there's an error in my list?)

Comment: The only “error” I’ve found in your list so far is really an error on Wizards of the Coast’s part: _Arms & Equipment Guide_ lists the dastana under “Shields,” even though it grants an armor bonus, requires Armor Proficiency (light), and is a reprint of the _Oriental Adventures_ item that was listed under “Shields and Other Additions.” But its presence under shields in your list is, of course, strictly accurate per what they published, so the error does not lie with you. Everything else I’ve checked has been flawless.