# Book of Exalted Deeds edition 3.0?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

Although, printed in 2003, both page 6 and 191 list all 3.0 books it is designed as a supplement to and doesn’t have the 3.5 revision stated on page 6 as it should for a 3.5 book would. Isn’t it a 3.0 ed book and not 3.5?

Comment: Hi. I guess you are thinking about the Book of **Exalted** Deeds?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1138/8610).

Answer (score 9):

*Book of Exalted Deeds* is one of the weird “3.25e” books that was written while the v.3.5 revision was being worked on. These books tend to have some discrepancies with respect to the final revision, since they were aiming at a moving target.

The said, *Book of Exalted Deeds* is one of the last books in this category, released well after the 3.5e core books. The overwhelming majority of its rules correctly refer to 3.5e rules, not 3.0e ones. One of the easiest ways to tell this is to look at classes’ skill lists: numerous skills were consolidated and renamed in the revision, so which skill list is usually the quickest way to tell. *Book of Exalted Deeds* consistently uses the 3.5e skill list.

Comment: Can you give some examples of 3.0 rules still appearing in _Book of Exalted Deeds_?

Comment: @QuadraticWizard No, because I don’t remember them offhand. I know they exist, I’ve come across them before, but actually trying to find them is more tedious than I can be bothered with. The discrepancy with the front matter not indicating the revision seems example enough.