# Where can I find the rules for the Oriental Adventures Scry skill?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, errata

I have the Oriental Adventures book, and the 2/6/2006 errata.

In a number of the new classes, there is a skill, `Scry (Int, exclusive skill)`, first appearing in the Shaman class on p23, but appearing as a class skill in a number of other classes.

However, I cannot find any definition or explanation of the Scry skill, except for an exception to Scry in the writeup of Void Disciple, p52.

*Ch4, Skills and Feats* lists Scry as a High skill that is honorable for a samurai to use.

Other than appearing on the sample character sheet, there does not appear to be any other significant mention or explanation of this skill.  It is not mentioned in the errata.

Where can I find a definition and explanation of the Scry skill, or should I just ignore it?

Comment: You may be interested in answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1138/8610).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Scry was removed from 3e in the 3.5e revision

You can find rules for the Scry skill in the 3e *Player’s Handbook* or SRD, but you shouldn’t. It was removed from the game quite intentionally. *Oriental Adventures* was updated for the 3.5e revision in *Dragon* magazine, vol. 318. I recommend you find a copy of that if you intend to use *Oriental Adventures*; if you can’t, you’ll have to houserule it. Not too hard to do in most cases, but it is more work.

In the case of the Scry skill, though, the answer’s easy: just ignore it. All it did was allow you to use or block the *scrying* spell, which was changed to be based on the subject’s Will save against your DC instead of your Scry skill checks. Which is why they removed it, it was stupid to have a skill for one spell, and to have a spell that didn’t work if you didn’t have points in a skill that did nothing else.

Comment: Not finding Scry in the SRD?

Comment: @nijineko [Here](https://www.dragon.ee/30srd/) is a version of the *3E* SRD. The Scry skill is, indeed, in the Skills section.

Comment: Ahah, looks like I only preserved the last copy of the SRD (3.5), and not the pre-update version. Thanks for correcting that miss on my part.