# What do I need to do to make Ghostwalk 3.5 compatible?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, conversion

One of my friends is wanting to use Ghostwalk but there are changes between 3.0 and 3.5 which require converting. What do I need to do to make it compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Can you?"  Yes, you can use 3.0 books reasonably seamlessly in 3.5.  Heck you can use 1e stuff too if you want, I've done it.

May you?  Depends on whether your GM allows it.  You might consider asking.

What would you need to do to convert?  Well, Ghostwalk has a huge swath of rules content in it, items, spells, abilities, monsters - so anything that would generally need converting because its rules changed.  Here's a link to general 3.0/3.5 changes you'd need to look out for. [How compatible are books for D&D 3.0 and D&D 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/what-are-the-major-differences-between-dd3-0-and-dd3-5)?  Determine what content you want to use out of Ghostwalk then run it by the conversion guide - and remember than specific monsters etc. do change in 3.5, compare vs. those books when it's something that exists in both editions.

Comment: my DM is Ok with it as long as i can find out what needs to be changed but really besides some skill differences i didnt see much else that changes.

Answer (score 21):

*Ghostwalk*'s second Web enhancement officially updates the product to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*. It's available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200105202451/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20031225a).