# The Sunless Citadel and its errors

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, published-adventures, errata

Is there any official errata for the adventure module by Bruce Cordell, The Sunless Citadel? Failing that, is there a decent-sized unofficial errata available on the web? Something more than "I changed these two things."

If anyone has a link for an update to 3.5 then that would be great. No sense in reinventing the wheel if I can help it.

Comment: Not really an errata, but in MM2 you can find the Twig Blight. The MM2 version is slightly different, for example its poison follows traditional poison rules, dealing ability score damage instead of HP damage. Since MM2 was published after Sunless Citadel I would use the MM2 Twig Blight.

Comment: Also, MM2 has a 3.5 update.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, twigblights. And the baby white dragon, I had him as a pet for a long time. The only errata published for Sunless Citadel was notes directly from author Bruce Cordell, and they're [located here](http://www.dndadventure.com/html/articles/errata_adventures.html).

> Reflex Save DC for pit trap on p. 20: "this old pit trap should be DC 16."
>
> Missing word: "...the last word in the boxed description of encounter 42 is 'wheelbarrow', as in 'rusted wheelbarrow'."

As for a conversion, no, but anyone who needs to do work to convert a 3e adventure to 3.5e really truly has too much time on their hands.  Run it as written, it's how we rolled in the 2000's.

Comment: +1 Calcryx is pretty cool. I did find that errata. It's the best I found and it's pretty meager lol. Fair enough for experienced DMs or anyone who prefers 3e. Guess a little discrepancy here and there is better than agonizing over counting copper pieces and small amounts of XP.

Comment: Only word on running it as written, care for spells that are substantially different. Since the Sunless Citadel is a low level adventure you shouldn't find many (maybe the Abilityname of the Animalname line) but be aware of those.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure he can read http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/what-are-the-major-differences-between-dd-3-0-and-dd-3-5 to find out about running 3.0 in 3.5 in general.

Comment: @mxyzplk♦ I will be running the Sunless Citadel in the future as an intro adventure for my party, may I ask how you managed to claim the baby white dragon as a pet? Knowing my players I can imagine them attempting the same and would like some perspective on what they might do.

Comment: @DancingKobold IIRC I took it as my animal companion and promised to drop Leadership on it once I got to level 6. That group considered RAW for "the dirty people" so wheeling and dealing like that was common. Mainly I roleplayed feeding it and caring for it. It was a little rowdy being evil but it was small enough it couldn't really hurt much, it was what 3 HD?  Later the GM let it advance to Very Young after the Leadership was taken.