# Help need for someone who knows nothing about D&D

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I was wondering if anyone could help me? My partner is a big D&D fan and I would like to get him some books for Christmas as a surprise. All I know is he likes 3.5ed and has 5 forgotten realm books already, as well as the main handbooks (which I bought him for Christmas a few years ago but he picked out). I have tried looking on the internet to see what the difference is between 3ed and 3.5ed but it just goes over my head. So if anyone could recommend some books that would be great as I don't want to buy the wrong books.

Thanks

Comment: (A) I think many here would like to help you; (B) I think the question's likely to get closed as "not fitting the Q&A format" as there's not an objective 'right' answer. But fear not--the closure will likely come along with a list of forums where this question *will* fit and where you should get a good answer. (And many of us participate on those forums, too.)

Comment: These aren't quite duplicates, but [How compatible are books for D&D 3.0 and D&D 3.5?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/how-compatible-are-books-for-dd-3-0-and-dd-3-5) and [How do you tell if a D&D book is 3.0 or 3.5?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/how-do-you-tell-if-a-dd-book-is-3-0-or-3-5/36990#36990) seem related to your question. They may be helpful to you.

Comment: Also note that 3.5 has been out of print for *many* years (apart from the core books that got reprinted), so whatever you decide on will need to be found secondhand.